# Issuing system commands in Linux from C, C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, system

I know that in a DOS/Windows application, you can issue system commands from code using lines like:

```
system("pause");
```

or

```
system("myProgram.exe");
```

...from stdlib.h. Is there a similar Linux command, and if so which header file would I find it in?

Also, is this considered bad programming practice? I am considering trying to get a list of loaded kernal modules using the `lsmod` command. Is that a good idea or bad idea? I found some websites that seemed to view system calls (at least system("pause");) in a negative light.

Comment: i think you can use system("lsmod") or system("/usr/bin/lsmod") to do it... (use `which lsmod` to see where it is)...  is this what you want?

Comment: Why would you want to call "pause"? if you want to wait for users press a button before continuing use getch(); or std::cin.get(); I agree very bad form to use system("pause");

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not surprisingly, the command is still

```
system("whatever");
```

and the header is still `stdlib.h`. That header file's name means "standard library", which means it's on every standard platform that supports C.

And yes, calling `system()` is often a bad idea. There are usually more programmatic ways of doing things.

If you want to see how `lsmod` works, you can always look-up its source code and see what the major system calls are that it makes. Then use those calls yourself.

A quick Google search turns up [this link](http://www.koders.com/c/fid0FA7E4B90C5B896C8585FD27C4766D268DF87776.aspx), which indicates that `lsmod` is reading the contents of `/proc/modules`.

Answer (score 16):

`system` is a bad idea for several reasons:

- Your program is suspended until the command finishes.
- It runs the command through a shell, which means you have to worry about making sure the string you pass is safe for the shell to evaluate.
- If you try to run a backgrounded command with `&`, it ends up being a grandchild process and gets orphaned and taken in by the `init` process (pid 1), and you have no way of checking its status after that.
- There's no way to read the command's output back into your program.

For the first and final issues, `popen` is one solution, but it doesn't address the other issues. You should really use `fork` and `exec` (or `posix_spawn`) yourself for running any external command/program.

Comment: Great explanation of the dangers. And yes, `posix_spawn()` is the preferred method.

Comment: Also note that for OP's specific need, parsing `/proc/modules` rather than using `lsmod` is the correct solution.

Comment: I've not seen posix_spawn() before, but WOW what a list of parameters. I feel it's worth adding that these downsides to system() are specific to what you're trying to achieve. I frequently use it specifically for the shell interpretation of the command (backgrounding the command excepted of course) where all I want is the side effect or exit code.

Comment: @boycy: Well `system` gives you a lot more than what you want it for. It messes up your signal handling, does non-thread-safe things, etc. in addition to bringing in the dangers of the shell.

Comment: "`system` gives you a lot more than what you want it for" - my point is that this isn't a _universal_ truth. Sometimes the listed behaviours are exactly what I want, so although `system` isn't always _right_, neither is it always wrong. (Though it is wrong in OP's case of course.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, lsmod does it by parsing the `/proc/modules` file.  That would be my preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are fork and exec.