# Multiple terminal processes in C

Tags: c, unix, process, terminal

I would like to, in C code, create more than one terminal processes. As in, I want to run `foo` in a terminal process, and then in a separate terminal process, I want to run `bar`. Is this possible? Could I do it with `system(char *)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [posix_spawn()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn). Here is an [example](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/subprocess/posix_spawn_example1.c.txt). Definitely do **not** call `system()` to launch new processes.

Comment: Hmm. What's wrong with `system()`? Do you recommend not using it merely because its execution is synchronous, which is probably not what the OP wants for this specific use case? Can you clarify your answer?

Comment: @Tomalak Correct, `system()` blocks and the OP wants more than one process, presumably at the same time. Also, `system()` goes through the shell, which most users don't want to do in reality. Here's a good [list of other issues with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622693/beginner-question-issuing-system-commands-in-linux-from-c-c/4622772#4622772).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "terminal process". You can't (easily?) create another process that somehow causes the user to have more terminals open, but you can use [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) to create a child process.

`fork` creates another copy of your process with the same initial state, except that it returns 0 in the child process, and returns some non-zero PID in the parent process. So a sketch would look like:

```
if (fork())
    system("bar");
else
    system("foo");
```

This causes your original program to spawn two processes, running `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: `fork()` returns a strictly positive integer in the parent process (namely the child's PID) and 0 in the child process, or -1 on error. Hence, `switch(pid = fork()) {/*case -1 / 0 / default*/}` is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be evil, assuming you are running X, you could launch xterm's like this:

```
while(processes to spawn)
{
    if(!fork())
        execlp("xterm", "-e", "foo"); // or "bar" or "baz" ...
}
```