# Program not registering my input correctly

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//function prototypes
void checkAnswer(char *, char[]);
int main(void) {
  char *strGame[5] = { "ADELANGUAGEFERVZOPIBMOU", "ZBPOINTERSKLMLOOPMNOCOT",
      "PODSTRINGGDIWHIEEICERLS", "YVCPROGRAMMERWQKNULTHMD",
      "UKUNIXFIMWXIZEQZINPUTEX" };
  char answer[80] = { 0 };
  int displayed = 0;
  int x;
  int startTime = 0;
  system("clear");
  printf("\n\n\tWord Find\n\n");
  startTime = time(NULL);
  for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    /* DISPLAY TEXT FOR A FEW SECONDS */
    while (startTime + 3 > time(NULL)) {
      if (displayed == 0) {
        printf("\nFind a word in: \n\n");
        printf("%s\n\n", strGame[x]);
        displayed = 1;
      }
    }
    system("clear");
    printf("\nEnter word found: ");
    fgets(answer, 80, stdin);
    checkAnswer(strGame[x], answer);
    displayed = 0;
    startTime = time(NULL);
  }
}
void checkAnswer(char *string1, char string2[]) {
  int x;

  for (x = 0; x <= strlen(string2); x++)
    string2[x] = toupper(string2[x]);
  if (strstr(string1, string2) != 0)
    printf("\nGreat job!\n");
  else
    printf("\nSorry, word not found!\n");

}
```

When I run the code, it doesn't register my input correctly.  It tells me that the word wasn't found.  I used toupper to make my input the same as my strings and strstr to compare my input with the strings.   I took this from a basic C programming book.  It used gets.  I know that you shouldn't use gets so I changed it to fgets.  Is this where the problem is?  Any suggestions?

Comment: to be in the last newline('\n') in the string that you entered in fgets does not take into account. You must remove the newline.

Comment: regarding the line: for (x = 0; x <= strlen(string2); x++), this line is one char too long. so it should be: for (x = 0; x < strlen(string2); x++) as there is no need to toupper('\n')

Comment: you need to remove the new line char(s) from the end of the user string, as suggested by others.

Comment: regarding the line: if (strstr(string1, string2) != 0), strstr returns a pointer or NULL, not 0, so the line should be: if (strstr(string1, string2) != NULL)

Comment: the '\n' needs to be replaced with '\0' so the read string is still properly terminated.  And get the strlen value AFTER replacing the newline with a null char.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the issue with the `\n` (newline) mentioned by BLUEPIXY -- namely, that `gets()` removes it but `fgets()` does not -- by reversing the terms in your call to `checkAnswer()`:

```
checkAnswer(answer, strGame[x]);
```

`checkAnswer()` then uses the same order with `strstr()`.  If you search for "foobar" in "foobar\n", `strstr()` will return a pointer.  But if you search for "foobar\n" in "foobar", it won't.

The newline is there because the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  So another way around this would be to add a `\n` to the end of all your `strGame[]` strings.  Or, you could remove any newline in the answer with:

```
void truncateAtNewline (char *str) {
    char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
    if (p) *p = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Yes, because a gets() does not account for the size of the input buffer. Buffer of large size may make your program either crash or produce undefined behavior.

Comment: @black_perl I'm not recommending `gets()`. The OP is right to use `fgets()` instead, but it creates a minor issue with the newline that must be taken into account and dealt with.

Comment: No problem.  If you think you have an answer to your question, tick the big checkmark at the top of the answer to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `fgets()` will leave the newline at the end of the string. When you type the word, then you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and `fgets()` interprets that as input.

So, a way to bypass this is to eat the newline by doing this:

```
fgets(answer, 80, stdin);
// go to the last position where the
// newline is placed and replace it
// with the null terminator
answer[strlen(answer)-1] = '\0';
```

Also here:

```
 for (x = 0; x <= strlen(string2); x++)
    string2[x] = toupper(string2[x]);
```

the `<=` is not needed, since you start from 0, thus change it to this:

```
 for (x = 0; x < strlen(string2); x++)
    string2[x] = toupper(string2[x]);
```

How I found your problem? I used printf to output the strings before comparing them.

```
void checkAnswer(char *string1, char string2[]) {
  int x;

  for (x = 0; x < strlen(string2); x++)
    string2[x] = toupper(string2[x]);
  printf("|%s|\n", string1);
  printf("|%s|\n", string2);
  if (strstr(string1, string2) != 0)
    printf("\nGreat job!\n");
  else
    printf("\nSorry, word not found!\n");

}
```

Output before my fix:

```
|ADELANGUAGEFERVZOPIBMOU|
|ADEL
|
```

Output after the fix:

```
|ADELANGUAGEFERVZOPIBMOU|
|ADEL|
```

Or you can use a function to  trim newlines and spaces. I have some methods [here](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/eat-spaces-and-newline-c/).

Consider also [not using system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622693/issuing-system-commands-in-linux-from-c-c).

Moreover, always add a `return 0;` line of code before your main() ends.