# How to get a ping response in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which has domain name column. I want to see which domain exist by pinging their domain names. I can get an individual ping response from following function.

```
ping <- function(x,stderr=FALSE,stdout=FALSE,...){
pingvec <- system2("ping",x,
                 stderr=FALSE,
                 stdout=FALSE,...)
if (pingvec == 0) TRUE else FALSE
}



ping("google.com")
[1] TRUE
```

Is there any R package where I can get ping response for entire column which has thousands of domain names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use `system()` commands - as a general rule in any programming language. The [main reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4622772/4770166) are security and portability issues.

The [`pingr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pingr/) package provides a possibility to ping a remote server within R:

```
library(pingr)
URLs <- c("google.com", "yahoo.com")  
sapply(URLs, ping)
#     google.com yahoo.com
#[1,]       14.6       171
#[2,]       14.7       171
#[3,]       14.6       171
```

---

**edit / comment**

Looking at the source code of the functions `pingr::ping()` and `pingr:::ping_os()` it appears that the package *does* use a call to `system()`. Therefore, I think that [security concerns remain](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/), since the OS function `ping` could be redefined to do something completely different and possibly harmful. What the package does seem to resolve are portability problems, since different methods are called depending on the OS.

Comment: Whether calling `system` is a security problem depends upon the context.  If the code is being run on arbitrary machines which you have no control over, then yes, `ping` could be redefined to be something else and there is a security problem.  If you want to ping a bunch of addresses from your own machine, that isn't an issue.

Comment: Its very slow. Taking lot of time,is there any other way which is faster? And then I want to see which websites does not ping.

Comment: @Neil The ping timeout can be changed on the system level. In linux systems an option to reduce this time would be `ping -i 0.2`. You could pass this option to pingr by using `URLs <- paste("-i 0.2",URLs)`. This should speed up the function. Don't know about options on other OS.

Comment: I meant to say the ping *interval*, not the timeout.

Comment: @RHertel  How can I use that option in pingr ?

Comment: @Neil This works on my computer: `URLs <- c("google.com", "yahoo.com") ; URLs <- paste("-i 0.2",URLs); sapply(URLs, ping)`. Essentially, the option `-i 0.2` is attached as a character string at the beginning of each URL. Hope this helps.

Comment: @RHertel  When I run above code it gives me all NA values `-i 0.2 google.com -i 0.2 yahoo.com
[1,]                NA               NA
[2,]                NA               NA
[3,]                NA               NA`

Comment: @Neil I'm afraid I can't help any further. There's probably a reason why the default interval is 1s. Maybe try to increase the value (0.2s is the smallest value allowed for non-superusers on my system, which is Ubuntu 16.04). Note that the URLs need to be defined again. You could try, e.g. `URLs <- c("google.com", "yahoo.com"); sapply(paste("-i", interval=0.4, URLs), ping)`.

Comment: @RHertel Still does not work. Thanks for your help and time. Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

We can wrap with `Vectorize` and do for multiple elements

```
ping1 <- Vectorize(ping)
ping1(c("yahoo.com", "google.com"))
ping1("google.com")
```