# How can i execute this shellcode " ls PathToDirectory > newFile.txt" in C to create a new file with the list of content of the directory

Tags: c, shell

How can I execute this shellcode `ls PathToDirectory > newFile.txt` in C to create a new file with the list of content of the directory.

I've tried but this gives me always an error. "ls: cannot access '>': No such file or directory"

I am using this code :

```
execl( "/bin/ls","ls","PathToTheDirectory" ,">","newFileTocreate.txt" , NULL);
```

Output:

> ls: cannot access '>': No such file or directory
>   newFileTocreate.txt

"Show the content of the directory"

Comment: Why do you have to do this in the shell? You can directly read the directory from your C code to get a llist of the files.

Comment: `execl` is certainly not the function to use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output redirection `>` is a shell construct that's not understood by `execl` family functions; they don't invoke a shell to run commands.

What happens is `>` is passed as an argument to `ls` which, therefore, says there's no such file in your current directory.

You have few options:

- You can use [`popen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to run the command & read the output and then you can write to the file.

  ```
  char buf[1024] = {0};
  FILE *fp = popen("/bin/ls PathToTheDirectory");
  while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
      /* write to newFileToCreate.txt */
  }
  ```
- [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) the file and duplicate((with `dup2`) its stdout and then exec it so that output is written to the file.

  ```
   int fd = open("newFileToCreate", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
   dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
   execl( "/bin/ls", "ls", "PathToTheDirectory", NULL);
  ```
- Use [`system(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) which invokes a shell. So you can the command as you have. Although, be aware that this option should be avoided whenever possible. See [Issuing system commands in Linux from C, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4622693/4389800)

  ```
  system("/bin/ls PathToTheDirectory > newFileTocreate.txt");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the system call like this example in dols.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){

        int ret = system("ls > listing.txt");
        if (ret) printf("ERROR: non-zero return %d", ret);

    }
```

- compile and run and check

```
[C]$ gcc dols.c 
[C]$ ./a.out 
[C]$ more listing.txt 
a.out
dols.c
```